# How to Resume Git Repository After Operating System Restore

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I have searched extensively for an answer to my situation to no avail. Please forgive me if this has been answered and I just for some reason couldn't find it.

I recently completely wiped my hard drive and reinstalled my OS (Xubuntu 20.04). After getting the OS installed, I synchronized all my files from my local backup to the restored system, which included the git repository I had on the previous OS install. Well, I made changes to one of the files in my repository and went to do a `git status` and I got a message saying, "Your branch is up-to-date."

I tried some things like, `git fetch`, `git init`, and still the same message as above.

Well, I read somewhere to remove the .git folder and do `git init` again and then `git add .` then `git commit -m "Message"` and then git `push -u origin master`. Now, I'm getting the message,

"fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository.

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists."

If anyone could pleas give me some guidance on this issue, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add origin to your `git` repository because you have removed the `.git` folder. Try the following

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git
# Set a new remote

git remote -v
# Verify new remote
origin  https://github.com/user/repo.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/user/repo.git (push)
```

For more details click [here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/using-git/adding-a-remote). Then push your changes to the `git` using

```
git push origin master
```

Don't forgot to move your `ssh` keys back to `~/.ssh` directory if you have a backup of them otherwise create new `ssh keys`

For pulling the latest data from repo., use `git pull`

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Your answer is getting me in the right direction, I believe. When I do the 'git push origin master' I now get this error:

Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again. See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: Yes, do a git pull to merge latest changes in master, I have included this in the last line of answer

Comment: Okay, I did that, and after a 'git pull' I get this message: "There is no tracking information for the current branch. Please specify which branch you want to merge with. See git-pull(1) for details. 'git pull <remote> <branch>' If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with: 'git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master'" Doing a 'git pull origin master' gave me an unrelated histories error. So, I tried the '--set-upstream-to' option and with a 'git pull' I get this error: (see following comment...)

Comment: New 'git pull' error: "error: Pulling is not possible because you have unmerged files. hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>' as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit."  What is meant by "fix them up?" Should I just run that 'git add/rm' command and see what happens? This is a nightmare. Haha. Thank you so much for your patience and assistance!

Comment: I found the file giving the merge conflict and I did a 'git add path/to/file.pdf' and now things seem to be going in the right direction. However, I changed a file to make sure all is well and when I do a 'git status' I get, "On branch master. Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'." I changed a local file, so it's not up to date. How do I get the synchronization going again? I'm really close here.

Comment: Got it! It appears your solution was the answer. Apparently, my terminal color scheme, Dark Pastels, made it to where I could not see that a 'git status' was in fact listing all the files that I modified. Go figure. So, thank you for your solution.